# Registering events of dynamically loaded com object through reflection

Tags: c#, com, activex, com-interop, ocx

In my application i have loaded an ActiveX control dynamically. I can use the methods and properties of this dynamically loaded control through reflection. But my problem is i can't access the events.

When i use the `GetEvent` method

```
(Type.GetEvent(string EventName)
```

it returns null value.

The Type of the dynamically loaded control is com object. So is there any way to resolve this issue? Please help me

Comment: Did you try `dynamic`?

Comment: Do you still have a managed interop library for this dynamically loaded ActiveX (built with TlbImp or as a project reference)?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel i loaded the ActiveX control dynamically, I can invoke methods and properties by reflcetion. But i need to register an event of this dynamic control, but the "Type.GetEvent" method always returns null value.

Comment: I mean to use [Dynamic language runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx)